# SSL сертификат Let`s Encrypt. Ошибка настройки сертификата

Tags: ssl, letsencrypt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В браузере без ошибок работает сертификат. А вот Яндекс Вебмастер выдаёт ошибку сертификата.

Comment: Промежуточный сертификат (chain) забыли подключить?

Comment: Видимо да, можно по подробнее?

Comment: Это вам для начала стоит рассказать поподробнее, где, чем и как вы подключали сертификат